# Unity - How To Spawn Obstacles at Different y levels

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, flappy-bird-clone

I am trying to make a game that has similar pipe spawning methods as flappy bird, although I cannot find a useable script as every "Tutorial" I see either is not modular AT ALL so it is extremely difficult to edit to fit my game, or could help but I cannot read the code as it shows the code at 144p (a bit of a exaggeration but it sure doesn't feel like it) so I need to know some methods of making a script for unity that has pipes (That I already have made) spawn at a certain point at different y levels. Any help would be appreciated a lot as I will turn to YouTube as a last resort for now on, thank you :)

Comment: Please share the code you already have here in your question and then we can probably tell you what and where to change to achieve what you are trying to do

Comment: I apologize but I do not have any code at the given time, I will try to rephrase the question, Basically I want to know how I would go across making a script for it. I am sorry that I did not make that clear

Answer (score 0):

Create vector 3, use random.range to randomize the y value.

Add that vector3 onto whatever position you are currently using.

Use instantiate and pass in the new position